# What is the proper Job hunting etiquette in the USA when your papers have expired?

Tags: new-job

My work permit expired this month, and I'm still waiting for the renewal to come through (it should be in by the end of August at the most). The thing is I'm not sure how it's seen in the US if someone starts applying or looking for a job before they can actually start working.

The question is: What is the etiquette when job hunting in the USA while waiting for papers to come through?  Is It considered bad form to apply when your availability may be a month or longer from the day you applied?  What should I be mindful of when applying?

Comment: We can't really tell you what to do in this situation. Apply, and see what happens. Worst case scenario you get rejected. If you want to know whether it's _legal_ then you should ask a lawyer, or simply post on Lawyers SE and see if they can help you out.

Comment: The general question may be worth addressing but note that in your case it is *incredibly* unlikely that you'll go through a complete hiring process in less than a month.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, it is permissible to apply, but to actually take the job, you should have your papers or be able to supply them on short notice.  If you bring your expired papers and explain that you are waiting for your renewal to go through, it shouldn't be a problem in most cases.  As it's already mid July, you may not have a solid offer until August anyway, so don't wait for the paperwork to go through.

If you get an offer to start beforehand, tell your employer that you are waiting for your updated papers to arrive (it's not a lie) and can supply them when you get them.

Again, follow up so you have a good idea when your papers will arrive

Comment: And if they ask questions about your eligibility to work in the US in the hiring process, be totally up front about the fact that the renewal is in process but not here yet.

Comment: Don't they have to present non-expired documents within 3 days of starting to complete the I-9 form?